# Are there Unicode symbols for even and odd numbers?

Tags: unicode, symbols

Using an option, I can specify whether even or odd days are valid. For the user interface I search now for suitable symbols to display these options. In mathematics there is no symbol for even and odd numbers, as far as I know.

Does anyone know whether there is perhaps something corresponding in Unicode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

Given that odd and even numbers are a mathematical concept and mathematics has no symbol for odd and even numbers, maybe except for `2N` and `2N+1`, you'll find it hard to find a non-existent symbols in Unicode.

You'd have to think of your own characters, or find some in Unicode and just redefine their meaning.